# How to configure extension path matching for interceptors in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This configuration used to work in my `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
private void addLoginInterceptor(final InterceptorRegistry registry, final HandlerInterceptor interceptor) {
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/**/*.login");
}

private void addAuthenticatedInterceptor(final InterceptorRegistry registry, final HandlerInterceptor interceptor) {
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/**/*.html", "/**/*.pdf", "/**/*.json");
}
```

but since upgrading to Spring 5.3.2 (using Spring Boot 2.4.1 BOM), it no longer works. I've tried adding

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(final PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
  configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
}
```

which didn't work.

The error I get is

> No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element

but as I said, the above config worked before. How do I get this working again?

Note that this application does not use Spring Boot; just the BOM for dependency management.

Comment: umm is /what/ever/foo/bar.login valid in your case??

Comment: @Antoniossss I guess not with the login paths, but definitely with the others. They could be any number of segments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
configurer.setPathMatcher(new ParsingPathMatcher());
configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This must be for an older version of Spring or something. The second two lines are the default, and the first line has a class that doesn't exist (`ParsingPathMatcher`). Do you have more explanation as to why you think this would work?

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to mark this answer "correct" because I hate it so much, but after all the fighting and trying different configs I found something that works. Prepare for UBER-KLUDGE!

```
private void addLoginInterceptor(final InterceptorRegistry registry, final HandlerInterceptor interceptor) {
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns(varLengthPattern(".login"));
}

private void addAuthenticatedInterceptor(final InterceptorRegistry registry, final HandlerInterceptor interceptor) {
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns(varLengthPattern(".html"));
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns(varLengthPattern(".pdf"));
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns(varLengthPattern(".json"));
}

private List<String> varLengthPattern(String suffix) {
  List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    paths.add(StringUtils.repeat("/*", i) + suffix);
  }
  return paths;
}
```

So as long as my path doesn't go more than 10 segments long, it will work. Feels like a duct tape solution, but it does what I needed it to. I'm still VERY open to better answers than this one.